# How to resolve dependency packages when installing httpd-devel apr-devel apr-util-devel yum on centos 5.6

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

I am trying to install httpd-devel apr-devel apr-util-devel centos 5.6. i got dependency problem

```
 Resolving Dependencies
 --> Running transaction check
---> Package apr-devel.i386 0:1.2.7-11.el5_6.5 set to be updated
 --> Processing Dependency: apr = 1.2.7-11.el5_6.5 for package: apr-devel
--> Processing Dependency: libapr-1.so.0 for package: apr-devel
 ---> Package apr-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.7-11.el5_6.5 set to be updated
 ---> Package apr-util-devel.i386 0:1.2.7-11.el5_5.2 set to be updated
  --> Processing Dependency: apr-util = 1.2.7-11.el5_5.2 for package: apr-util-devel
  --> Processing Dependency: openldap-devel for package: apr-util-devel
   --> Processing Dependency: libaprutil-1.so.0 for package: apr-util-devel
  --> Processing Dependency: db4-devel for package: apr-util-devel
  --> Processing Dependency: expat-devel for package: apr-util-devel
  ---> Package apr-util-devel.x86_64 0:1.2.7-11.el5_5.2 set to be updated
   ---> Package httpd-devel.i386 0:2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
  --> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 for package: httpd-devel
  ---> Package httpd-devel.x86_64 0:2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
   --> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 for package: httpd-devel
  --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package apr.i386 0:1.2.7-11.el5_6.5 set to be updated
  ---> Package apr-util.i386 0:1.2.7-11.el5_5.2 set to be updated
  --> Processing Dependency: libsqlite3.so.0 for package: apr-util
  --> Processing Dependency: libldap-2.3.so.0 for package: apr-util
  --> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.3.so for package: apr-util
  --> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0 for package: apr-util
   --> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.4 for package: apr-util
  --> Processing Dependency: liblber-2.3.so.0 for package: apr-util
  ---> Package db4-devel.x86_64 0:4.3.29-10.el5_5.2 set to be updated
  ---> Package expat-devel.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3 set to be updated
  ---> Package httpd-devel.i386 0:2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
  --> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 for package: httpd-devel
  ---> Package httpd-devel.x86_64 0:2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
  --> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 for package: httpd-devel
  ---> Package openldap-devel.x86_64 0:2.3.43-12.el5_7.10 set to be updated
   --> Processing Dependency: cyrus-sasl-devel >= 2.1 for package: openldap-devel
   --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package cyrus-sasl-devel.x86_64 0:2.1.22-5.el5_4.3 set to be updated
  ---> Package db4.i386 0:4.3.29-10.el5_5.2 set to be updated
  ---> Package expat.i386 0:1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3 set to be updated
  ---> Package httpd-devel.i386 0:2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
  --> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 for package: httpd-devel
 ---> Package httpd-devel.x86_64 0:2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
 --> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 for package: httpd-devel
  ---> Package openldap.i386 0:2.3.43-12.el5_7.10 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.2 for package: openldap
 ---> Package postgresql-libs.i386 0:8.1.23-1.el5_7.3 set to be updated
  ---> Package sqlite.i386 0:3.7.0.1-1.el5.art set to be updated
 ---> Package sqlite.x86_64 0:3.7.0.1-1.el5.art set to be updated
  --> Running transaction check
 ---> Package cyrus-sasl-lib.i386 0:2.1.22-5.el5_4.3 set to be updated
 ---> Package httpd-devel.i386 0:2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
 --> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 for package: httpd-devel
---> Package httpd-devel.x86_64 0:2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 set to be updated
 --> Processing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 for package: httpd-devel
  --> Finished Dependency Resolution
 httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.i386 from updates has depsolving problems
   --> Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-      devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.i386 (updates)
 httpd-devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-devel-      2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.x86_64 (updates)
  Error: Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-  devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.i386 (updates)
  Error: Missing Dependency: httpd = 2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3 is needed by package httpd-  devel-2.2.3-53.el5.centos.3.x86_64 (updates)
  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
   You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                    package-cleanup --dupes
                    rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
   The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

can you anybody guide me how to resolve this issue?. I need to install this yum packages on the centos 5.6 machine.

httpd version is httpd-2.2.21-1.w5

apche version is

Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov 14 2011 18:03:07

Comment: What was the output from the cleanup commands it gave you (`package-cleanup` and `rpm -Va`)? — do you have duplicate packages installed or something like that?

Comment: how to put clean up command? can you give an example

Comment: Just like it said, try running the three commands that it suggested. At the very least, they'll probably tell you what the problem is, and possibly fix it:

`You could try running:` `package-cleanup --problems`
                    `package-cleanup --dupes`
                    `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

If you don't have `package-cleanup` you might have to `yum install yum-utils` first

Comment: i tried these three commands                                        1. package-cleanup --problems                                          Setting up yum
Reading local RPM database                                          but same dependency problem will occur
Processing all local requires
No problems found
2. package-cleanup --dupes                                              Setting up yum

Comment: What was the output from the cleanup commands it gave you (package-cleanup and rpm -Va)? — do you have duplicate packages installed or something like that? Perhaps update your question with their output…

Comment: i got the following output when putting package-cleanup commands.                                                             Setting up yum                                                       Reading local RPM database                                          Processing all local requires                                      No problems found

Comment: 1. this should be on serverfault.com
2. you are probably mixing x86 and x86_64 so you are having multiarch issues

Answer (score 3):

You don't even list your original command, so we can't be sure how you're trying to install it.

From the output, my guess is that you have an old httpd/httpd-devel package holding you back.  On top of that you have both i386 and x86_64 versions of them installed.

Start by removing httpd-devel with

```
yum remove httpd-devel.i386 http-devel.x86_64
```

then try again with

```
yum -y install httpd-devel apr-devel
```

Comment: I am also getting dependency issues. I tried install them getting # yum install apr-util-ldap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * updates-newkey: s3-mirror-us-east-1.fedoraproject.org
 * fedora: s3-mirror-us-east-1.fedoraproject.org
 * updates: s3-mirror-us-east-1.fedoraproject.org
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package apr-util-ldap available.
Nothing to do
[root@ADM-POC-MAP-APACHE-2.2.21 rpm1]# yum install systemd-units
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Comment: Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * updates-newkey: s3-mirror-us-east-1.fedoraproject.org
 * fedora: s3-mirror-us-east-1.fedoraproject.org
 * updates: s3-mirror-us-east-1.fedoraproject.org
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
No package systemd-units available.
Nothing to do

Comment: --> Missing Dependency: libldap-2.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by package httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64 (httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm)
Error: Missing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by package httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64 (httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm)

Comment: Error: Missing Dependency: libldap-2.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by package httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64 (httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm)
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.21-1.fc16 is needed by package httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64 (httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm)
Error: Missing Dependency: apr-util-ldap is needed by package httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64 (httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm)
Error: Missing Dependency: systemd-units is needed by package httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64 (httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm)
Error: Missing Dependency: libdb-4.8.so()(64bit) is needed by package

Comment: httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64 (httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm)
Error: Missing Dependency: liblber-2.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by package httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64 (httpd-2.2.21-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm)

Answer (score 0):

You may also try: **yum update --skip-broken**. It may not fix broken packages but at least can install other updates.